# How to format a line to display as multiple line inside the same cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel sheet where a column contains memory informations formatted this way on one unique line in each cell:

```
{(slot  2048 MB,1,667,Unknown),(slot  2048 MB,2,667,Unknown),(slot  2048 MB,3,667,Unknown),(slot  2048 MB,4,667,Unknown)}
```

How can I format each cell to display the content of one parenthesis per line:

```
(slot  2048 MB,1,667,Unknown),
(slot  2048 MB,2,667,Unknown),
(slot  2048 MB,3,667,Unknown),
(slot  2048 MB,4,667,Unknown)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do it with just formatting. But if you use `SUBSTITUTE` in a different cell, you can add in some line breaks. If your data is in A1, put this in B1:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "),(", ")," & CHAR(10) & "(" )`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear whether you want to enter this information manually or via a formula but, similar to another answer, you can use CHAR(13).

[Technically char(13) is a carriage return whereas char(10) is a line feed]

eg

```
=A1 & CHAR(13) & A2 & CHAR(13)...
```

along with various string replacement or substring strategies as required.

If you're entering text manually then you can insert a line break by using Alt+Enter within a cell.